# python data visualization bokeh

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

Hello there wise programmers of the world

I´m 2 issues
I have my dataset like this:

[image]

The first and main issue is that he is printing some weird plots, like this:

[image]

Makes no sense in comparison with the original plot that I´m using as reference ->

[image]

The second issue is that he is printing some error messages ->

```
ERROR:bokeh.core.validation.check:E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name: female_literacy [renderer: GlyphRenderer(id='1fb09ca6-67a9-47c6-a528-a01030829385', ...)]
ERROR:bokeh.core.validation.check:E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name: female_literacy [renderer: GlyphRenderer(id='4ed4e766-485c-409a-9d61-1e0fdbd81c62', ...)]
ERROR:bokeh.core.validation.check:E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name: femaleliteracy [renderer: GlyphRenderer(id='13f9c2a6-d8fc-49b2-909b-ddb50313f619', ...)]
ERROR:bokeh.core.validation.check:E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name: femaleliteracy [renderer: GlyphRenderer(id='379aabbe-feee-4324-9819-6a019b615991', ...)]
```

My code goes like this:

```
# Import row from bokeh.layouts
from bokeh.layouts import row

df = pd.read_csv('literacy_birth_rate.csv')
df.columns = ['Country ', 'Continent', 'femaleliteracy', 'fertility', 'population']
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# Create the first figure: p1
p1 = figure(x_axis_label='fertility (children per woman)', y_axis_label='femaleliteracy (% population)')

# Add a circle glyph to p1
p1.circle(x='fertility', y='femaleliteracy', source=source)

# Create the second figure: p2
p2 = figure(x_axis_label='population', y_axis_label='femaleliteracy (% population)')

# Add a circle glyph to p2
p2.circle(x='population',y='femaleliteracy', source=source)

# Put p1 and p2 into a horizontal row: layout
layout = row(p1,p2)

# Specify the name of the output_file and show the result
output_file('fert_row.html')
show(layout)
```

******edited***********

[image]

[image]

***************editing again***********************

```
 Import row from bokeh.layouts
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure

df = pd.read_csv('literacy_birth_rate.csv')
df.columns = ['Country', 'Continent', 'femaleliteracy', 'fertility', 'population']
df.dropna(inplace=True)
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# Create the first figure: p1
p1 = figure(x_axis_label='fertility (children per woman)', y_axis_label='femaleliteracy (% population)')

# Add a circle glyph to p1
p1.circle(x='fertility', y='femaleliteracy', source=source)

# Create the second figure: p2
p2 = figure(x_axis_label='population', y_axis_label='femaleliteracy (% population)')

# Add a circle glyph to p2
p2.circle(x='population',y='femaleliteracy', source=source)

# Put p1 and p2 into a horizontal row: layout
layout = row(p1,p2)

# Specify the name of the output_file and show the result
output_file('fert_row.html')
show(layout)
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the code you showed here reproduces the errors? The errors mention "female_literacy" which is not found in your code.

Comment: you have space after Country, try to delete this first.. `df.columns = ['Country ']`

Comment: yes, I´ve deleted the space, remains the same... thanks though...

Comment: where is `female_literacy` in the code?

Comment: there is no `female_literacy` anywhere... I don´t know **from where he is taking that** !!!!???

Comment: check your csv file, if this is it: https://github.com/wblakecannon/DataCamp/blob/master/16-interactive-data-visualization-with-bokeh/data/literacy_birth_rate.csv

Comment: yes, it´s exactly that one... but I´ve renamed the column name from `female literacy` to `femaleliteracy` ... taking out white space...

Comment: you have empty spaces and then repeating column names on line 177, try to delete those

Comment: yes, I´ve did `df.dropna(inplace=True)` and the dataset was reduced to 162 rows only, but still not giving the right plot !!

Comment: then upload rest of the code, idk either

Comment: ok, just a second... it´s there...

Comment: I think I have a clue now... I´ve restarted the kernel, and one of the errors `ERROR:bokeh.core.validation.check:E-1001 (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name: female_literacy [renderer: GlyphRenderer(id='1fb09ca6-67a9-47c6-a528-a01030829385', ...)]
` isn´t showing now
he was there because in some prior cells  there was, actually a `female_literacy` column being used, in a prior call to the figure method

Comment: but the plot still not working..

Comment: I wonder if the `femaleliteracy` and `fertility` columns are `object`... and not float, if that could be a problem?

Comment: I´ve used `df.femaleliteracy = df.femaleliteracy.astype(float)
df.fertility = df.fertility.astype(float)` to convert from `object` type to float, and now the plot is working... thanks a lot ... !!!

Answer (score 0):

I´ve used

```
df.femaleliteracy = df.femaleliteracy.astype(float) 
df.fertility = df.fertility.astype(float)
```

For newbies it´s important to indicate pay attention to **column types**...

to convert from object type to float, and now the plot is working... thanks a lot ... !!!

the other problem was related to the fact that `female_literacy` was being used in a prior function call to the figure()... restarting the kernel solved that !!!